# Share product in social media

Tags: html, reactjs, facebook, linkedin-api, share

I have a problem with show details of products in sharing on Facebook or LinkedIn. I send the correct URL but is showing details of the site. The front-end of the site is reacting js version 17.0.2, the back-end is API WordPress and I use the library react-share.

I try to change the library ShareThis-reactjs but is the same problem.

```
import React from "react";
import {FacebookShareButton,LinkedinShareButton,LinkedinIcon,FacebookIcon,
} from 'react-share';
import './styleBtnShare.css';
const BtnPartage = (props) => {return (
    <>
        <div className="btnsSShare" style={props.style}>
            <FacebookShareButton
                url={props.url}
             title={props.title}
            image={props.image}
             description={props.content.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gm, '')}
            >
                <FacebookIcon size={40} round={true} />
            </FacebookShareButton>

            <LinkedinShareButton
                url={props.url}
                title={props.title}
              image={props.image}
              description={props.content.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gm, '')}
            >
                <LinkedinIcon size={40} round={true} />
            </LinkedinShareButton>
            
        </div>
        
    </>

);
}
export default BtnPartage;
```

Comment: Please share code snippets.

Comment: Which URL are you sharing?

Comment: The scraper does not care for any client-side JavaScript, so if that's what is supposed to set your OG meta tag values, that won't work. And Facebook does not let you specify title, description and thumbnail dynamically any more either - those are taken from the OG meta tags the URL returns. You need a server-side pre-rendering solution.